# JSON from PHP file result was code, do not text

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have code PHP in file update_customer.php to save information customer

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh');

$response = array( 'status' => 0, 'message' => '', 'typeinsurance' => '', 'thoigianmua' => 0 );

if (empty($_GET) && !empty($_POST) && count($_POST) == 7 && isset($_POST['fullname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && 
    isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['cost']) && isset($_POST['typeinsurance']) && 
    isset($_POST['typepay']))
{
    require_once ('./../include/database.php');
    $database = new Database();

    $time = time();

    $_POST['thoigianmua'] = $time;

    if ($database->insert('customer', $_POST)){
        $response['status'] = 1;
        $response['typeinsurance'] = $_POST['typeinsurance'];
        $response['thoigianmua'] = $time;
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

and code JQUERY to sent data, but My JSON get

```
Object {status: 1, message: "", typeinsurance: "<?php echo $_POST['typeinsurance']; ?>", thoigianmua: 1440642246}
```

Please help me, thank in advance

Comment: Show us the PHP code that generates this output.

Comment: Can you show a sample of JSON that you expect and the input from the fields that are supposed to generate it?

Comment: this is my PHP code
`$response['status'] = 1;

$response['typeinsurance'] = $_POST['typeinsurance'];

  $response['thoigianmua'] = $time;`

Comment: It looks like you are sending the actual string `<?php echo $_POST['typeinsurance']; ?>` via post field `typeinsurance` as I understand, but I find it hard to correlate your code to the output - can you post more code that actually generates the response and the code which sends the request?

Comment: i want to show JSON
`Object {status: 1, message: "", typeinsurance: "xehaibanh", thoigianmua: 1440642246`

Comment: @MrKen What is the value of `$_POST['typeinsurance']` before you generate your `$request` then?

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the form? It sounds like you're not setting the value of the `typeinsurance` input correctly.

Comment: `var typeinsurance = $('#typeinsurance').val();`
It is hidden input

Comment: but it working in localhost very good

Comment: No, the PHP code that creates the form. It looks like your form has `value="<?php echo $_POST['typeinsurance'];?>"` in it.

Comment: @MrKen Can you actually give us the value of the field when it is created (the html line) and as it is received by PHP?

Comment: Use VIew Source and look at the form in the browser.

Comment: my form is in phtml file, it working in localhost very good

Comment: @MrKen We need some answers to our comments. Also, is your server properly parsing the .phtml files? i.e. does it evaluate the PHP at all?

Comment: @Barmar I use Jquery.load to load phtml file and have post method, i cannot view source

Comment: Then look at it in the Elements tab of DevTools. What do you see in the `value` attribute?

Comment: Thank everybody so much, my phtml is not working in server

Answer (score -1):

You php code has error for sure that's why its returning the data in a way that you not expected.

The wrong part is `<?php echo $_POST['typeinsurance']; ?>`  you have given the php code as string.

you have to check your php file

Comment: this is my code PHP
`<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh');

$response = array( 'status' => 0, 'message' => '', 'typeinsurance' => '', 'thoigianmua' => 0 );

require_once ('./../include/database.php');
 $database = new Database();

 $time = time();

 $_POST['thoigianmua'] = $time;

 if ($database->insert('customer', $_POST)){
  $response['status'] = 1;
  $response['typeinsurance'] = $_POST['typeinsurance'];
  $response['thoigianmua'] = $time;
 }

echo json_encode($response);
`

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because your answer doesn't have anything to help him fix the problem.

Comment: @MrKen Don't try to put code in comments. Edit the question.

Comment: i put code in question and have notice for code but it not allowed

Comment: @MrKen You already have code in the question, you can add more.